# Android Shared Preferences Not Saving?

Tags: java, android

I have an app that is supposed to do the following: The first (main) activity displays
a passcode that changes every minute.The time remaining in seconds before the passcode changes.
The first activity also has a button to verify the passcode. Once the user clicks the “Verify” button in the first activity, the second activity (verification window) should be launched and become visible to the user. The second activity should have a ListView that displays all timestamps for all passcodes that were previously generated, and one button to clear the list. Once the user exits the app, the list will clear but the last timestamp will be stored in a shared preference and will be restored the next time the user opens the application.The application should support landscape and portrait orientations and should handle screen orientation changes at run time.

So far everything should be working until the point where the app's last timestamp is saved in shared preferences. When I exit the app and reload it the timestamp is not saved and unsure why. I have included the code below. Thanks hopefully someone can help.

```
    package com.example.security_token_app;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    static String PREF_NAME = "SharedPrefFile";
    static SharedPreferences SavedTimeStamp;
    static SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    static String TIMESTAMP_KEY = "TIMESTAMP_KEY";
    private TextView countDownTextView;
    TextView passCodeTextView;
    static int passCode;
    static String currentDateTime;
    static ArrayList<String> arrayIntegerList = new ArrayList<String>();
    Button verifyButton;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        countDownTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4_time_remaining);
        passCodeTextView= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3_passCode_int);
        verifyButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        SavedTimeStamp = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME,0);
        editor = SavedTimeStamp.edit();
        if(MainActivity2.isSaved==true)
        {
            //MainActivity2.isSaved=false;
            MainActivity2.restoreTimeStamp();
            openSecondaryActivity();
        }
        createPassCode();
            new CountDownTimer(60000, 1000)
            {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long timeUntillFinished)
                {
                    countDownTextView.setText("seconds remaining: " + timeUntillFinished / 1000 % 60);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish()
                {
                    createPassCode();
                    start();
                }
            }.start();
            verifyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
//                    if(MainActivity2.isSaved==true)
//                    {
//                        MainActivity2.restoreTimeStamp();
//                    }
                    openSecondaryActivity();
                }
            });
    }
    public void createPassCode()
    {
        int minute = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        passCode=minute*1245 + 10000;
        String timeStamp = getTimeStamp();
        arrayIntegerList.add(timeStamp);
        String passCodeStr = Integer.toString(passCode);
        passCodeTextView.setText(passCodeStr);
    }

    public void openSecondaryActivity()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public static int getPassCode()
    {
        return passCode;
    }

    public static String getTimeStamp()
    {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        currentDateTime = dateFormat.format(new Date());
        return currentDateTime;
    }



}

package com.example.security_token_app;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity
{

    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ListView listView;
    Button clearButton;
    int count;
    String item;
    static ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    static boolean isSaved = false;
    boolean adapterSet = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        clearButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.passButton);

        for(String temp:MainActivity.arrayIntegerList)
        {
            arrayList.add(temp);
        }
        //adapter resset here? loses the saved time stamp
//        if(isSaved==true) //added
//        {
//            isSaved=false;
//            return;
//        }
        if(isSaved==false)
        {
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
        isSaved=false;

        clearButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                count = adapter.getCount();
                item = adapter.getItem(count-1);
                adapter.clear();
                adapter.add(item);
                saveTimeStamp();
            }
        });
    }

    public void saveTimeStamp()
    {
        int i = adapter.getCount();
        if(isSaved==true)  //changed from i==1
        {
            isSaved=false;
            return;
        }
        String lastTimeStamp = adapter.getItem(i-1);
        if(!lastTimeStamp.isEmpty())
        {
            MainActivity.editor.putString(MainActivity.TIMESTAMP_KEY, lastTimeStamp);
            MainActivity.editor.commit();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "time stamp saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            isSaved = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "nothing saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
    }

    public static void restoreTimeStamp()
    {
        String lastTimeStamp = MainActivity.SavedTimeStamp.getString(MainActivity.TIMESTAMP_KEY, "NOT LOCATED");
        adapter.add(lastTimeStamp);

        //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "time stamp restored", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root_constraint_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:layout="@layout/activity_main">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1_blueBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:background="@color/sky_blue"
            android:text="test" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2_passCode_string"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:text="PASS CODE"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="38sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3_passCode_int"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="38sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="test" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4_time_remaining"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            tools:text="1:00 seconds remaining"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Verify"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />




    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity2">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout1"
        android:layout_width ="match_parent"
        android:layout_height ="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:layout="@layout/activity_main">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1_blueBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:background="@color/sky_blue" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:dividerHeight="32dp"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/passButton"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="PASS"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />









    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: You don't need to make SharedPreferences static variables, you can get them from anywhere you have context/activity

Comment: that doesn't fix the problem

Comment: Yeah, just pointing out

Answer (score 0):

```
count = adapter.getCount();
item = adapter.getItem(count-1);
adapter.clear();
adapter.add(item);
saveTimeStamp();
```

Can you try calling saveTimeStamp() before clearing adapter?
Like this

```
saveTimeStamp()
count = adapter.getCount();
item = adapter.getItem(count-1);
adapter.clear();
adapter.add(item);
```

Comment: doesn't work same result

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to create SharedPreferences in App class.override oncreate method in this class

```
public class App extends Application{

public static SharedPreferences prefs;

@Override
public void onCreate(){
super.onCreate();
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

}

Then you can use prefs everywhere in your project like this:

```
  editor = App.prefs.edit();
```

Comment: And when is onCreate() called?

Comment: whenever your application runs onCreate called at the first.You can just Log it to see.

Comment: it doesn't fix the problem though..